# ScrollView Autolayout working with Label but not Custom Control

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicontrol

I'm working on a project that has a custom segmented control in a UIScrollView. I want to use auto layout to position the segmented control. I'm using this project as my model: https://github.com/honghaoz/UIScrollView-and-AutoLayout

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    var screenBounds: CGRect { return UIScreen.main.bounds }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Setup scroll view

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:20/255.0, green:119/255.0, blue:61/255.0, alpha:255/255.0)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        // Setup constraints
        var views: [String: UIView] = [
            "scrollView": scrollView
        ]

        var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

        // External constraints
        constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[scrollView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
        constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[scrollView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)


        // Internal constraints
        // Note: to let scrollView determines its contentSize, four edges should be explicitly specified
        let v1 = newLabelWithText("v1 v1 v1 v1 v1 v1 v1 v1 v1 v1")
        scrollView.addSubview(v1)
        views["v1"] = v1

        //Create Segmented Control
        let segmentedB = YSSegmentedControl(
            //Set Frame in Callback (Required)
            frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 60),
            titles: [
                "Yes",
                "No"
            ],
            action: {
                control, index in
                print ("segmented did pressed \(index)")
        })
        scrollView.addSubview(segmentedB)
        views["v4"] = segmentedB

        let v2 = newLabelWithText("v2 v2 v2 v2 v2")
        views["v2"] = v2


        let v3 = newLabelWithText("v3 v3 v3 v3 v3")
        views["v3"] = v3
        scrollView.addSubview(v3)

        // Horizontal, fully specified
        constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-200-[v4]-300-|", options: .alignAllLastBaseline, metrics: nil, views: views)
        // Vertically, fully specified
        constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-200-[v3]-1000-|", options: .alignAllLeading, metrics: nil, views: views)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
        print("scrollView.contentSize: \(scrollView.contentSize)")
    }
}
```

For some reason, auto layout works just fine with the text labels but not with the segmented control. The callback requires that I input parameters for CGRect, so I simply set the width and height and leave the position parameters at zero. This worked when there was no scrollview, but its not working now.

Also, I'm not using storyboards in this project. All constraints and views are created programmatically.

Any Help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add this line before adding constraints

```
segmentedB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Whenever you add constraints programmatically you should set this property to false in order for constraints to take effect on the view